# TensorFlow tf.data.Dataset and bucketing

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

For an LSTM network, I've seen great improvements with bucketing.

I've come across the [bucketing section in the TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.training#Bucketing) which (tf.contrib).

Though in my network, I am using the `tf.data.Dataset` API, specifically I'm working with TFRecords, so my input pipeline looks something like this

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(TFRECORDS_PATH)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.map(_scale_function)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes={.....})
```

How can I incorporate the bucketing method into a the `tf.data.Dataset` pipeline?

If it matters, in every record in the TFRecords file I have the sequence length saved as an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various `bucketing` use cases using `Dataset API` are explained well [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/kernel_tests/bucketing_test.py).

**`bucket_by_sequence_length()` example:**

```
def elements_gen():
   text = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2], [8, 9, 0, 2]]
   label = [1, 2, 1, 2]
   for x, y in zip(text, label):
       yield (x, y)

def element_length_fn(x, y):
   return tf.shape(x)[0]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=elements_gen,
                                     output_shapes=([None],[]),
                                     output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32))

dataset =   dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length(element_length_func=element_length_fn,
                                                              bucket_batch_sizes=[2, 2, 2],
                                                              bucket_boundaries=[0, 8]))

batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:

   for _ in range(2):
      print('Get_next:')
      print(sess.run(batch))
```

**Output:**

```
Get_next:
(array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
   [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], dtype=int32), array([1, 2], dtype=int32))
Get_next:
(array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
   [8, 9, 0, 2]], dtype=int32), array([1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: In my use case, actually there are many features and one of them is a sequence, lets say its `x['seq']` in every record, how would I apply it to that element only?

Comment: you need to change your `elements_gen()` function to `yield(x['seq'], y)`

Comment: I don't have an `element_gen()` since I'm reading from a TFRecords file, couldn't I change the `element_length_func` to return `tf.shape(x['seq'])[0]`? And why did you call `del y`?

Comment: The link leads to a deleted site.